# JQuery push down menu look and feel not working as it should

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

So I have created a fiddle to show you what i mean :

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/Y6bab/)

The problem is that the menu is showing the background color of the div that is hidden but I need it to be transparent. I have tried to make it transparent but with no joy. Not sure if another div needs adding but I tried this? So effectively my aim is for the arrow icon to be sat on top of a transparent background and the grey show when the menu slides down.

```
<div id="nav-mobile" style="width: 100%; text-align:center;">

    <div style="background-color: #E6E8E8;">
    <ul style="list-style:none; margin:0; padding: 0;">
        <li class="topmenutitle">JUMP TO:</li>   
        <li class="topmenulink"><a href="" class="menutop">What we do</a></li>        
        <li class="topmenulink"><a href="" class="menutop">All things us</a></li>        
        <li class="topmenulink"><a href="" class="menutop">CodeEd</a></li>        
        <li class="topmenulink"><a href="" class="menutop">Let's talk</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div style="background-color: transparent;">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/saki/nuoveXT/128/Small-arrow-down-icon.png" /></a>
    </div></div></div>

<div id="header">header</div>

.menutop:link {text-decoration: none; color: #F60;}
.menutop:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #F60;}
.menutop:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: #F60;}
.menutop:focus {text-decoration: none; color: #F60;}
.menutop:active {text-decoration: underline; color: #F60;}

body{
    margin: 0;
}

#header{
    background-image:url(http://www.photo-dictionary.com/photofiles/list/4615/6106crash_test_dummy.jpg);
}

li.topmenutitle{padding-bottom: 27px; padding-top: 37px; color: #CCC; font-size: 24px;}

li.topmenulink{width: 100%;height: 16px;line-height: 26px;font-size: 24px;text-align: center;padding-bottom: 27px; padding-top: 17px;}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? `nav-mobile` is hidden and doesn't have a background color associated with it and shortly there after you declare `<div style="background-color: #E6E8E8;">` and later `<div style="background-color: transparent;">`. Which one of those is incorrect? What should the background of menu be, exactly?

Comment: The #E6E8E8 is for the menu background when it reveals - take a look at the fiddle the grey band along the top need to be transparent but when it pushes down the grey is the background of the list it reveals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually how you have your div's structured. If you look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6bab/3/ You'll see that they all pile up on top of each other at the start so while your calls are technically correct, you aren't achieving the results you want because they are all layered on top of one another and only the `<div style="background-color: #E6E8E8;">` has color and thus is what is displayed.

I added two css classes:

```
.transparent{
    background: transparent;   
}
.bgSet{
    background: #E6E8E8;
}
```

Gave your starting div a new class:

```
<div id="nav-mobile" class="transparent" style="width: 100%; text-align:center; border:1px solid #d00;">
```

And added two new lines to your jquery click function:

```
$('#nav-mobile').toggleClass('transparent');
$('#nav-mobile').toggleClass('bgSet');
```

This should solve your problem and remember to test how your divs align, even if it's a really rough test like the one I used with the borders. They usually give up the ghost very shortly after you give them all unique and distinct properties.

**Edit**
The other way to achieve this is to add an id and a background color in your css to the line below:

```
<div style="background-color: transparent;">
```

As this is currently transparent, the background behind your arrow will display whatever is behind it. Once you do that, you can just give `#nav-mobile` a background color in your css and you won't have to worry about any new jQuery.

It all comes down to knowing how you structured your divs, and how they are overlapped.

Two solutions for two different methods of display.